# In PYTHON how do I associate values in dataframes to pass them both to a SQL update?

Tags: python, pandas, oracle, dataframe, cx-oracle

Use Case:
Project team emails the DBAs an excel with a list of hundreds of usernames that need to be updated for a system  in an oracle db. The dba should be able to run a python script that automates the process of importing the data from the excel, connecting to the db and updating the table.

My Idea:
Use pandas to import the data from the excel into a dataframe, cx_oracle to connect to the database, a for loop to go through the dataframe and a sql update to make the changes in the database.

My Problem:
It kind of works. There is either an issue with my logic or my choice of data structures. The for loop updates the old usernames for each of the new usernames so I end up just changing a ton of the old usernames into the last new username in my dataframe.

Code:

```
import pandas
import cx_Oracle

df = pandas.read_excel(input("Please type the name of the excel spreadsheet provided:"))

"""
DBA would type in the name of the xlsx provided which would contain two columns for the
current username and what their new username should be. Would look similar to the info below
with hundreds of entries.

Usernames to be changed     new usernames

John.Doe                   jdoe
William.Wallace            wwallace
Theodore.Roosevelt         troosevelt
Andrew.Jackson             ajackson
Thomas.Jefferson           tjefferson
Alexander.Spotswood        aspotswood
"""

old_usernames = df['Usernames to be changed'].unique()
new_usernames = df['new usernames'].unique()

for old_username in old_usernames:
    dataframe_values = df[df['Usernames to be changed'] == old_username]

for new_username in new_usernames:
    dfv = df[df['new usernames'] == new_username]



connection = cx_Oracle.connect("sys", input("Please type the database password:"), "localhost:1521/orcl", mode=cx_Oracle.SYSDBA)
cursor = connection.cursor()
for old_username in old_usernames:
    update_username = "UPDATE SYSTEMUSERS SET USERNAME = '" + str(new_username) + "' WHERE USERNAME = '" + str(old_username) + "'"
    cursor.execute(update_username)
    connection.commit()
cursor.close()
connection.close()

"""
Results of running this code.

What is looked like before running code.

user_first_name  user_last name   usernames

John             Doe              John.Doe
William          Wallace          William.Wallace
Theodore         Roosevelt        Theodore.Roosevelt
Andrew           Jackson          Andrew.Jackson
Thomas           Jefferson        Thomas.Jefferson
Alexander        Spotswood        Alexander.Spotswood


What is looks like after running the code.

user_first_name  user_last name   usernames

John             Doe              aspotswood
William          Wallace          aspotswood
Theodore         Roosevelt        aspotswood
Andrew           Jackson          aspotswood
Thomas           Jefferson        aspotswood
Alexander        Spotswood        aspotswood


What I want it to look like.

user_first_name  user_last name   usernames

John             Doe              jdoe
William          Wallace          wwallace
Theodore         Roosevelt        troosevelt
Andrew           Jackson          ajackson
Thomas           Jefferson        tjefferson
Alexander        Spotswood        aspotswood
"""
```

Possible Solution: I cannot find out if this is possible but if I could associate the values from the dataframe so that the old username would only be replaced by its specific new username then that would solve all my problems. Otherwise if I could break up my loop somehow so that it would descend through the dataframe in order. My final thought is if I should be using something like an array instead of a dataframe so that I could assign each value in the array to a variable and set some type of counter so that a different loop could go through each of them as a set. I have tried a lot of different ways and have read everything I can find and still cannot make it work.

Disclaimer:
I am a noob who has learned 100% of what little he knows from open sources on the internet and I have been researching this issue for a week and am so close, but just can't figure it out. This is the first program I have ever written that interacts with anything outside of itself. If anyone could point me in the right direction then I would greatly appreciate it.

Additional information:
OS: Windows 10.0.18363
Programming Language: Python 3.8.5 Windows x86-64
Database: Oracle Solaris x86 systems, 64-bit, Oracle SQL Developer 20.2.0.175.1842-x64
Excel: 16.0.13001.20266 32-bit

Comment: Your code is wrong. Inside the update loop, old_username varies across all users, but the variable new_username is always the same. It contains the last value it had inside the loop where you define dfv.

Answer (score 0):

You can write this in a more concise way as follows:

```
mapping = df[['Usernames to be changed','new usernames']]
mapping.columns = [['old','new']]
mapping = mapping.drop_duplicates()
if mapping.old.nunique() < len(mapping):
    raise ValueError('Mapping inconsistent 2 olds point to 1 new')
if mapping.new.nunique() < len(mapping):
    raise ValueError('Mapping inconsistent 1 old points to 2 new')
```

Then you can iterate to apply the changes:

```
connection = cx_Oracle.connect("sys", input("Please type the database password:"), "localhost:1521/orcl", mode=cx_Oracle.SYSDBA)
cursor = connection.cursor()
for _, r in mapping.iterrows():
    update_username = "UPDATE SYSTEMUSERS SET USERNAME = '" + r.new + "' WHERE USERNAME = '" + r.old + "'"
    cursor.execute(update_username)
    connection.commit()
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

I don't see why you need to commit inside the loop. You can do that at the end:

```
for _, r in mapping.iterrows():
    update_username = "UPDATE SYSTEMUSERS SET USERNAME = '" + r.new + "' WHERE USERNAME = '" + r.old + "'"
    cursor.execute(update_username)
connection.commit() # <----
```

might be faster.

You might also want to verify that your table may not be interpreted with chains of substitutions, e.g.:

```
old      new
John     Johnny
Johnny   Dave
```

in which case, multiple substitutions might occur for John: John -> Johnny -> Dave

If you want to deal with such cases, you might want to perform 2 substitutions.

1. Replace with temporary placeholder

```
John -> TMP_name_1
Johnny -> TMP_name_2
```

2. Replace with final values

```
TMP_name_1 -> Johnny
TMP_name_2 -> Dave
```

Your placeholders should be devised such that they cannot be confused with normal user names. One way is to use a character which is forbidden for user names (e.g. '#').

Comment: This answer has some merits but it shows interpolating data into the SQL statement which should _never be done_ because it is a security risk and affects performance and scalability.  Use [bind variables](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html) instead.

Comment: If the data is appropriately logical, it would be a lot more efficient to use a single [`executemany()`](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html) (with bind variables) instead of a loop with many `execute()` calls.  Also, you can turn on autocommit and remove the `commit()` call which will save another round trip.

Comment: Thank you @ChristopherJones, you really pointed me in the right direction. The iterrows() function was a life saver. I found that I did not need to map the columns as you did nor did I have any issues with it being "interpreted with chains of substitutions." I also took the commit out of the loop as you recommended. I am still looking into bind variables and some error handling, but so far so good. I will post my final code when I am done for anyone out there that may be having the same issues.